# increment numbers in a file that match a given pattern by a fixed amount

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a script that searches PDFs for certain errors and logs instances of them in a file with the corresponding page number. (Using Pdfgrep, in case you're interested.) The PDFs are for sections of a book and so aren't always numbered in print starting from 1. For each error in the log I want to show number that's actually printed on the page, called the folio, for ease of reference, rather than the PDF page number I currently have.

Not all lines in the log are errors. Here is some sample output:

```
Searches run on vol1.pdf, 01-06-2016

S01 SPACED SEMICOLON
77:  ences                                      Unit for Italian Studies: ; Dir C. KENNEDY      SUMMERS, P. M., Tropical Veterinary Science
143:BRAC Business School: ; Head Dr MD               BISWAS                                      Internet: www.diu.ac.bd
143:BRAC Development Institute: ; Dir Prof.        Dir for Student Welfare: GOUTAM KUMAR         Private control
261:Basic Institute of Biosciences: ; tel. (12)      College of Business Administration: Ir MARIA  Academic year: February to December
261:Basic Institute of Exact Sciences: ; tel.                                                      atinguetá
261:Basic Institute of Human Sciences: ; tel.        Committee on Ethics: Dr RODRIGO RICCI         Vice-Rector: MARILZA VIEIRA CUNHA RUDGE
299:Documentation sur les Traditions et les                                                        Interpreters (ASTI): ; Dir Dr ETIENNE ZÉ
328:              Political Science:            CRESPI, B. J.                         ing: ; tel. (604) 291-5240; f. 1987; Dir Dr R.
```

The file in the example starts at p81, captured in the script as $folio. For all lines that start with a number between 2 and 4 digits long followed by a colon I want to replace that number with N+($folio -1).

I had thought to use a loop like this to go through the log line by line.

```
while read line
    do
        # magic here

    done < $log
```

I'm fairly new to command line stuff. My first thought was to use grep ^[0-9]{2, 4} and somehow save that to a variable too then calculate, but while googling it seems maybe sed or awk might be more useful? I've found lots of answers that are for incrementing numbers by 1 etc. but nothing quite like this, and I'm unsure how to proceed. I'd be extremely grateful for any suggestions.

The $folio value differs every time so I'm collecting that via user input along with the $log filename to work on.

The headers (e.g. S01 SPACED SEMICOLON) need to remain intact.

Comment: shell is for creating/destroying files and processes and sequencing calls to commands, not for manipulating text. grep is only for finding a regexp in a file and printing the result. sed is only for making simple substitutions on individual lines (it has language constructs to do more, but they have been obsolete since the mid-1970s when awk was invented). awk is for every other text manipulation task, including whatever it is you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question to clarify where the `folio` value appears in your input file and include the expected output given that sample input.

Comment: @EdMorton `awk is for every other text manipulation task`, i dunno, sometimes perl has better functionality.

Comment: @EdMorton I don't necessarily mean just briefer, for example the `e` flag on substitutions is very useful in certain situations, where i am not aware that awk has anything comparable.

Comment: @EdMorton It evaluates the second part of the substitution so for example you can do `s/\d+/$&*10/ge` to multiply all numbers in the file by 10.

Comment: @EdMorton I've added an edit that hopefully explains about the origin of the $folio value. This is a long way from the core part of my daily work, and will only be used occasionally, so if there's a choice where one tool is clearer than another that would be best. From reading other replies it sounds like awl fits this profile?

Comment: @EdMorton I personally find the perl to be clearer, and whilst it is a very basic problem the awk solution is already becoming quite convoluted. Both languages (AFAIK) are turing complete so obviously anything can be done in either, I just think that sometimes perl is more clear(has built in documented functionality) sometimes. As for the NAN requirement `perl -pe 's/\d+/$&!=0&&10\/$&||NAN/ge'` should do it i think.

Comment: @EdMorton All of the constructs are documented and in vanilla perl with no modules, there really aren't that many constructs to learn. Whilst it is incredibly easy to write bad perl scripts it doesn't mean the same functionality cannot be written in a clear way.  In your awk example with `X` though, it almost looks as though you are agreeing with me?

Comment: @EdMorton I personally think that is clearer than your awk, but I suppose it just comes down to preference. Just to note though lots of awk's constructs are misused constantly though to make up for missing inbuilt functionality. The amount of script i see on here that use RS and FS for things other than separating fields and records is ridiculous. Anyway if your done then i suppose i am as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Perl is a  bit clumsy but:

```
perl -nle 's/^(\d{2,4}):/$1+82 . ":"/e && print' log

159:  ences                                      Unit for Italian Studies: ; Dir C. KENNEDY      SUMMERS, P. M., Tropical Veterinary Science
225:BRAC Business School: ; Head Dr MD               BISWAS                                      Internet: www.diu.ac.bd
225:BRAC Development Institute: ; Dir Prof.        Dir for Student Welfare: GOUTAM KUMAR         Private control
343:Basic Institute of Biosciences: ; tel. (12)      College of Business Administration: Ir MARIA  Academic year: February to December
343:Basic Institute of Exact Sciences: ; tel.                                                      atinguetá
343:Basic Institute of Human Sciences: ; tel.        Committee on Ethics: Dr RODRIGO RICCI         Vice-Rector: MARILZA VIEIRA CUNHA RUDGE
381:Documentation sur les Traditions et les                                                        Interpreters (ASTI): ; Dir Dr ETIENNE ZÉ
410:              Political Science:            CRESPI, B. J.
```

That says... *"Process the file "log" and if you find a line that starts with 2-4 digits and a colon, calculate a replacement line. That line must have the number you found plus 82 and a colon. If you find any like that, print them"*

It's kind of hard to explain, but anything in `(...)` on the left gets numbered and is available for use as `$n` on the right side. So the 2-4 digits we find become available as `$1` in the replacement.

The bit that is doing the magic is the `e` which means *"execute some more Perl to calculate the replacement string"*.

If you want the other lines (i.e. the headers and lines that don't start with numbers) to pass through intact as well, change the `&&` into `;`. And, in fact, as @123 kindly points out in the comments, if you want that, you can go with:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d{2,4}):/$1+82 . ":"/e' log

Searches run on vol1.pdf, 01-06-2016

S01 SPACED SEMICOLON
159:  ences                                      Unit for Italian Studies: ; Dir C. KENNEDY      SUMMERS, P. M., Tropical Veterinary Science
225:BRAC Business School: ; Head Dr MD               BISWAS                                      Internet: www.diu.ac.bd
225:BRAC Development Institute: ; Dir Prof.        Dir for Student Welfare: GOUTAM KUMAR         Private control
343:Basic Institute of Biosciences: ; tel. (12)      College of Business Administration: Ir MARIA  Academic year: February to December
343:Basic Institute of Exact Sciences: ; tel.                                                      atinguetá
343:Basic Institute of Human Sciences: ; tel.        Committee on Ethics: Dr RODRIGO RICCI         Vice-Rector: MARILZA VIEIRA CUNHA RUDGE
381:Documentation sur les Traditions et les                                                        Interpreters (ASTI): ; Dir Dr ETIENNE ZÉ
410:              Political Science:            CRESPI, B. J.
```

Comment: You can skip the `l` and `n` flags, and remove `&& print`, and just use the `p` flag. Unless they don't want the headers...

Comment: @123 Many thanks for your insights. I have added them in.

Comment: Thanks, yes I do want to keep the headers. I'll edit the original post to make that clear.

Comment: This looks like it could work nicely. However the number to increment by won't always be 82. Assuming I capture this as variable before executing this line of perl, can I just call that in place of the 82 in your example above? Sounds obvious, but I tried doing just that by replacing it with $num and it didn't work.

Comment: You'd need the Perl script in double quotes os the shell expands the `$num`, so use `perl -pe "s/^(\d{2,4}):/\$1 + $num . ':'/e" log`

Comment: Excellent, thanks, that's got it working. I added `cp $log "folios-$log"` higher up to create a version of the log to pipe the results into, and have renamed the `num` variable to `offset`, so the final code now looks like `perl -pe "s/^(\d{2,4}):/\$1 + $offset . ':'/e" $log &> folios-$log`, and it works! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Excellent - glad to be of assistance. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The awk script below relies on features of POSIX awk that are not present
# in legacy awk and are not enabled by default in some other awks (e.g.
# older GNU awk).  POSIX_AWK identifies a POSIX-compliant awk to use.
POSIX_AWK='/usr/bin/awk --posix'

# ...

folio=7

# ...

$POSIX_AWK -F ':' -v offset=$(($folio - 1)) '
/^[0-9]{2,4}:.*/  { sub(/[0-9]*/, $1 + offset) }
                  { print }
' $1
```

The `awk` program is embedded in the shell script.  Arithmetic expansion is used to compute the line number offset, which is then pre-assigned to an `awk` variable via a `-v` option (bash does this part when it expands the `awk` command line).  The `-F ':'` option tells `awk` to use the colon as a field separator; this is used as a convenience for extracting the leading number from numbered lines.  The program reads each line of the file specified by `$log`, substitutes the adjusted line number in lines that have a line number, and in every case prints the possibly-modified line to the standard output.

Comment: `GNU awk requires --posix to support interval quantifers in regexes` No it doesn't...

Comment: @123, well, if you want to pick nits, then you can use the more specific `--re-interval` instead.  The docs specifically say, "Interval expressions are only available if either --posix or --re-interval is specified on the command line", and the program does not work with GNU `awk` if `--posix` is omitted and `--re-interval` is not used.  I have clarified the code comment.

Comment: @JohnBollinger RE intervals have been enabled by default since gawk 4.0 which is now several years old and itself out of date. If you do have a prehistoric gawk and cant get a new one, though, then you should use `--re-interval` instead of `--posix` as the latter disables all other gawk-specific functionality, e.g. `gensub()`. Also, don't enclose any scripts in double quotes as it makes the rest of the code complicated and fragile, always use single quotes, and see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to use shell variable values in awk scripts.

Comment: @EdMorton, my ancient `gawk` (v3.1.7) is the one provided by still-supported RHEL 6 and its clones, and it is likely to still be seen in other parts of the wild as well.  In any event, the point of using `--posix` is specifically to rely on the features of POSIX `awk`, both for clarity and for compatibility, though the latter is largely moot in this particular case.  I have, however, updated the script in light of your other advice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you should get a newer gawk as you are missing a TON of immensely useful features (FPAT, sorted_in, BEGINFILE/ENDFILE, indirect function calls, 4th arg to split(), and true multi-dimensional arrays to name a few). See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History.